# sendmailR: how to handle occasional "Unknown SMTP code" errors

Tags: r, error-handling, sendmailr

I'm using sendmailR in my R script to send notifications.

*Sometimes* notification fails with the following error:

```
Unknown SMTP code: 452
Error in if (code == lcode) { : argument is of length zero
```

Execution halts.

How can I handle such errors, so that even if notification fails the script runs on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the `try` function around `sendmail` (assuming you use `sendmail`, if not then wrap it around the function or code that produces the error) this way:

```
 try(sendmail(from,to,subject), silent=T)
```

You can set silent to `FALSE` if you want the error message to appear but still continue with the process

Comment: I'd rather use `tryCatch`, so that you can react on the error message, but more importantly: don't be lazy to write `TRUE` instead of an uppercase `t`, as strange things can happen :)